# I want to make a custom drawable in android studio using xml but could not get result that I want

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable, layer-list

I want to make the background of my layout in android as given below I tried in android studio using layer list and shapes  but could not get result anyone expert here please help me how to make the background as given below

[image]

I Have tried this code but have not gotten my result. I want a background drawable.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:topRightRadius="15dp" android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

I also use Layer list I have no idea how I can get my result

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--Shadow Layer-->

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="40"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="0">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px" />
                <solid android:color="#01000000" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:right="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1px"
                android:left="1px"
                android:right="1px" />
            <solid android:color="#01000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--===============-->

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="40"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="0">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                <padding android:bottom="1px" />
                <solid android:color="#09000000" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:right="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding android:bottom="1px" />
            <solid android:color="#09000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--===============-->

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="40"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="0">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1px"
                    android:left="1px"
                    android:right="1px" />
                <solid android:color="#10000000" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:right="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1px"
                android:left="1px"
                android:right="1px" />
            <solid android:color="#10000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--===============-->


    <!--ForeGround-->

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="40"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="0">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#d4e5ff" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:right="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#d4e5ff" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: I can set the background I just want this background drawable in XML  then I will set in layout as a background

Comment: sorry, i don't understand, it's in xml drawable, do you want to make this by vctor?

Comment: I updated my question please review it again and help me if you can

Comment: Please check and let me know,  the new answer helped  you or not

Comment: No this is not as I show you in the reference image

Comment: thank you so much I find out my solution. Please vote up for my this question